# How to divy up a large file amongst python threads

Tags: python, multithreading, io

I have a very large file, ~1Gig, and I want to run threads that read parts of the file in parallel.

```
NUM_THREADS = 50
FILE_NAME = "some/file"

def read_chunk(offset, lines_to_read):
  # Read 'lines_to_read' number of lines from FILE_NAME, starting at 'offset'

def divide_work():
  num_lines = sum(1 for line in open(FILE_NAME))
  lines_per_thread = math.ceil(num_lines/NUM_THREADS))

  for i in range (0, NUM_THREADS):
    offset = i * lines_per_thread
    thread = Thread(target = read_chunk, args = (offset, lines_per_thread,)) 
    thread.start()
    thread.join()
```

Let's assume that the number of lines in the file will divide evenly into the number of threads. How do I read a certain number of lines from a certain line offset? I know about 'seek', but that uses bytes and I need to use lines.

Comment: IO to a single drive generally cannot be parallelized. look up consumer producer patterns.

Comment: It's great when people downvote your question but provide no feedback as to why they did it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threading will only buy you a performance increase if the process can be split into tasks that do not have dependencies on common resources, such as disk I/O.

In your scenario, your bottle neck is reading file the file from the disk which is limited to the I/O speeds provided by your disk.  You might be able to see a performance increase if you create a thread to process the information as it is read from the disk.  For example 2 threads.  The first threads is managing the disk I/O and dumping the data to a memory queue.  Second thread processes the data in the memory queue using CPU resources (performing hashes, data comparisons, etc...)

If you need the entire contents of the file before you begin processing it, I don't believe that there is much that you can do except look at upgrading your drive, or using a Ram Disk.